# Curl NSS error -12190 - Error in TLS handshake

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, openssh, curl

I am getting below error while trying to download a package from a URL through putty:

Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request

> Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
>
> CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>
> CApath: none
>
> NSS error -12190
>
> Error in TLS handshake, trying SSLv3...
>
> GET /NagiosEnterprises/nrpe/releases/download/nrpe-3.1.1/nrpe-3.1.1.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
>
> Host: github.com
>
> Accept: */*

But for some url it works perfectly as below:

> Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
>
> Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
>
> CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>
> CApath: none
>
> SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>
> Server certificate:
>
> subject: CN=*.mariadb.org,OU=Domain Control Validated
>
> start date: Oct 15 19:34:00 2017 GMT
>
> expire date: Oct 18 20:07:53 2018 GMT
>
> common name: *.mariadb.org
>
> ```
>   issuer: CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.",L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US
> ```
>
> GET /f/mariadb-10.1.31/source/mariadb-10.1.31.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
>
> Host: downloads.mariadb.org
>
> Accept: */*

Could someone help me to fix this.

Comment: // , What research did you do on this before posting? How would we reproduce the error?

Answer (score 2):

I had this error with `curl -v`.

I solved it by changing tls version:

`curl --tlsv1.2 https://(...)`

hth